# Accessing a list in a map in JSP

Tags: jsp, el

As said in the title, I would like to access a list stored in a map.
Here are some precisions :  I have an object of this type : `Map<A, List<B>>` named `generic`. I would like to get the first value of the stored list.

I tried this : `generic[${objectA}][0]` where `objectA` is of type A.

Any ideas why this fails ?

Comment: I guess you're overcomlicating. Don't try to do complex logic in presentation.

Comment: Please do not overgeneralize EL as JSTL. EL is not JSTL. To learn what exactly JSTL is, carefully read [our JSTL wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). I removed the wrong `[jstl]` tag from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should not nest EL expressions. You should see EL `${...}` as one big scope where various variables can interact with each other. Just get rid of the nested EL expression altogether.

```
${generic[objectA][0]}
```

This works provided that the `equals()`/`hashCode()` of `A` isn't broken.

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)